# Default argument value is overriding provided argument?

Tags: php, function, default-arguments

I have a function in PHP, which has some arguments default to `null`, so that I can easily call it with less than the full number of arguments.
The problem is, that when I use a null-defaulted argument directly, I get the given argument, but when I try to copy that value to another variable, the variable only gets the default value of `null`.
It looks like this:

```php
// inside my MySQLI wrapper class...
public function bind(&$stmt, $types = "", &$arg1, &$arg2 = null, &$arg3 = null /* this goes up to 20; it's auto-generated by another script */)
{
    echo "dumping...";
    var_dump($arg1); // var_dump shows value from function call (string(0))
    var_dump($arg2); // ditto
    echo "...dumped";
    if ($arg2 != null) $foo = $arg2; var_dump($foo); echo "foo"; // var_dump shows that $foo is NULL
    /* ... */
}
```

I call the function like this, from another script:
(It's a dummy script dealing with trucks and cars.)

```php
$make = "";
$model = "";
$year = 0;
$license = "";
list($error, $message) = $mysql->bind($stmt, "", $make, $model, $year, $license);
```

My `bind()` function is a wrapper to MySQLI's `bind_param()` and `bind_result()` functions.
I've only included the top couple lines, because it's failing at that point already, before it even gets to the actual logic.

Right now, it just looks like it's a bug in PHP, because this doesn't follow what I know about how variables, arguments, default arguments, and references work.
Furthermore, this problem only appears to manifest itself in my real code, and doesn't appear in my simple php file that I coded up to test this.

**Further info:**

`$foo` gets assigned `NULL`, when `$arg2` is an empty string, `""`, and properly gets assigned when it is a non-empty string. Empty strings are still valid strings, so why is PHP doing this?

Comment: I've tried it, and I have no problem: http://codepad.org/9cioWS04

Comment: Can you show the code that's actually producing the problem? If the code you posted doesn't produce it, then there must be a difference between the two (or their contexts) even if you believe they should be functionally identical. It might also help to see how you're calling the function.

Comment: Oh, also: `null` is probably a bad default value for testing, because lots of things can result in a variable being set to null. I recommend changing the default value in your code to something else. If the variable still ends up as null, then your problem isn't related to the default value.

Comment: Updated with actual code. @octern: My parameters are set to sensible values (e.g. strings of length zero) and immediately get nullified by the function in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `!=` comparison. What happens is that PHP [type-juggles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) at least one of your variables, and as such, `"" != null` evaluates to false. The table part-way down [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) shows what will happen for comparisons between different types. A type-strict form `!==` is needed:

```php
if ($arg2 !== null)
    $foo = $arg2;
```